# Subclass of Subclass fluent nHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

My model looks like this:

```
public class SelectionItem : BaseEntity // BaseEntity ==> id, timestamp stuff
{//blabla}

public class Size : SelectionItem
{//blabla}

public class Adultsize : Size
{//blabla}
```

I would like to use class-hierarchy-per-table-method of fluent nhibernate

```
public class SelectionItemMap : BaseEntityMap<Entities.SelectionItem.SelectionItem>
{
    public SelectionItemMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Picture);
        Map(x => x.Code);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("SelectionItemType");
    }
}
```

and reset a DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn on the following subclass:

```
public class SizeMap : SubclassMap<Size>
{
    DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("SizeType")
}

public Adultsize : SubclassMap<Adultsize>
{}
```

But this doesn't work.

I found a solution on the web: [link text](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/05/fluent-nhibernate-subclass-syntax-changes/)
but this method is depreciated according to resharper.

How to solve it? thank you for further informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn() in the SubclassMap. It takes the classname as discriminator value.

Correct version of code

```
public class SelectionItem : ClassMap<SelectionItem>
{
    public SelectionItem()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("SelectionItemType");
    }
}

public class Size : SubclassMap<Size>
{
}

public class Adultsize : SubclassMap<Adultsize>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use class-hierarchy-per-table-method use use one column as discriminator and then define the value of that descriminator for each concrete class.

Try something like this:

```
    public class SelectionItem : ClassMap<SelectionItem>
    {
        public SelectionItem()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("SelectionItemType");
        }
    }

    public class Size : SubclassMap<Size>
    {
        public Size()
        {
             DiscriminatorValue("Size")
             DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("SizeType");
        }
    }

    public class Adultsize : SubclassMap<Adultsize>
    {
        public Adultsize()
        {
             DiscriminatorValue("Adult")
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Torkel 
Thx a lot. it worked like a charm.
Just one thing - I didn't set a discriminator value and fluent took the class name as discriminator value.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work, DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn() isn't available in a SubclassMap.